# Adding GPS tag to Image metadata using python exif module

Tags: python, gps, exif

I have few images that do not have any GPS information (metadata) in the EXIF file. So when I get/read the EXIF information it does not show that as expected. I am trying to add GPS information but am getting the following error.

RuntimeError("can't yet add to images without a subsequent IFD 1")

Here is the block of code that adds the GPS information to the image

```
from exif import Image

with open("my_image.jpeg", "rb") as imgFile:
    img1 = Image(imgFile)
    img1.set("gps_latitude", (37.0, 14, 3.6))
    img1.set("gps_latitude_ref", 'N')
    img1.set("gps_longitude", (115, 48, 23.99))
    img1.set("gps_longitude_ref", 'W')

    # Tried the following too but get the same error
    img1.gps_latitude = (37.0, 14, 3.6)
    img1.gps_latitude_ref = 'N'
    img1.gps_longitude = (115, 48, 23.99)
    img1.gps_longitude_ref = 'W'


with open("my_newImage.jpeg", "wb") as new_image_file:
    new_image_file.write(img1.get_file())
```

I have removed all the surrounding code to keep this small

I also tried assigning the values instead of setting them but it still gave me the same error. I was expecting that one of them would add the GPS tags to the metadata but that did not happen so I am sure I am missing something.

Comment: You neglected to include a full traceback. [Tell us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which line elicited the RuntimeError. Posting `my_image.jpeg` would be helpful.

Comment: Related: https://exif.readthedocs.io/en/latest/known_limitations.html

Comment: I think this error is because the tags your setting don't exist in the image file.